# Driver for Validity Sensors Fingerprint scanner

Tags: drivers, login, security, fingerprint-reader

```
prakhar@pr3d4tOr:~$ lsusb -s 001:003 -v

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0018 Validity Sensors, Inc. Fingerprint scanner
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass        17 
  bDeviceProtocol       255 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x138a Validity Sensors, Inc.
  idProduct          0x0018 Fingerprint scanner
  bcdDevice            0.78
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                0 
  iSerial                 1 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           46
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           4
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               4
```

I have searched high and low but I cannot get this to work. All questions related to `138a:0018` are either *unanswered* or *old*. Any help guys?

Comment: Searched for the USB ID and found a bug, says it's been fixed. You can look through the comments for more info: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libfprint/+bug/827669

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, so after a lot of hair pulling and googling, I finally got my fingerprint sensor to work:

**EDIT** (03/01/2015): **Building the package from source**. You might need to set up a build environment first. Make sure that you have packages `$sudo apt-get install autoreconf libusb libusb-dev libnss3 libgdk-pixbuf2 git libtool`:

[Script for auto build and install](http://bit.ly/1HFkW2A) (written by me and shared from my Dropbox). `cd` to wherever you downloaded the script to and and run it with `superuser`:

```
$ chmod +x install.sh
$ sudo ./install.sh
```

**And voila**. Go to user accounts, and you'll see a fingerprint login option.

If you're using `ecryptfs` ([What is this?](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/ecryptfs.html)) for `/home`, you will encounter [this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libfprint/+bug/998367) at login. [Fix](http://fun.kyco.de/2011/12/25/finger-print-reader-vs-encrypted-home/).

**EDIT** (08/10/2014): You can also build your own driver by compiling `libfprint` patched with `138a:0018` and `138a:0017` drivers (see 03/01/2014). Their licenses apply, obviously.
I don't know for sure, but you can probably build this on a `32-bit` system as well.

**EDIT** (02/10/2014): After switching to Arch Linux, I recently found out that this driver (`libfprint-vfs5011-git`) is present in `AUR`. You can download the updated version from [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libfprint-vfs5011-git/) for this package (I'll update this answer soon to include instructions as well). EDIT: Added instructions, see 03/01/2014.

**EDIT** (13/09/2014): After recent updates to `fprint`, the fingerprint recognition is pretty awesome :P

**Pre-built**. (See the **03/01/2014** edit for the latest git version):

1. Open up a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and add the PPA for `fprintd`.

   `$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fprint`
2. Update your installation.

   `$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
3. Get the required packages.

   `$ sudo apt-get install fprintd libpam-fprintd`
4. [Download](http://bit.ly/1lCFD70) the driver for the fingerprint scanner (shared via my Dropbox). *Add a comment if the download is not working*. **See the latest edit (02/10/2014) for a repository version**.
5. `cd` to wherever you downloaded the driver to.
6. Install the driver.

   `$ sudo dpkg -i fprint-vfs5011_0-1_amd64.deb`

Comment: Where did you got the 138a:0018 driver from? I have the 138a:0017 sensor and I am (nothing personal) quite wary against bit.ly links pointing to an unknown Dropbox share from a user I don't know. Seriously +1 you got this working, but can you explain how you got to the specific driver?

Comment: The driver is built from this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libfprint/+bug/827669) (@Nattgew mentions it above). I downloaded it sometime back and I do not know why it's not present in Ubuntu upstream updates. Anyway, I **reuploaded** it to my dropbox and shared it.
Besides, I think `138a:0017` already has driver support. You can try this but I cannot claim this works for `138a:0017`. I have only tested it on `138a:0018`, `trusty`.

Comment: 138a:0017 doesn't work either

Comment: @jplandrain Should support `138a:0017` now.

Comment: Is there a patch available for `138a:0010` as well?

I have `Bus 001 Device 005: ID 138a:0010 Validity Sensors, Inc. `
and the install.sh mentioned above doesn't have the patch  so I get 
`mv: cannot stat ‘0001-lib-Add-VFS5011-driver-v2.patch’: No such file or directory
./install.sh: line 29: ./0001-lib-Add-VFS5011-driver-v2.patch: No such file or directory
./autogen.sh: 2: ./autogen.sh: libtoolize: not found
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.`

Comment: This does not work!

Comment: @Jason I updated the script.

Comment: Dropbox download doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: The dropbox download link is broken. It was said by  @Björn  a year ago as well :D. Fix for this is will be appreciated.

Comment: yeah, it would be cool if you could update the link for your dropbox. It seems to be broken. I would even be down to donate a little something if you would. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The link is broken. If somebody have the working link please update the link.

Comment: Sorry guys, I know the link is broken but unfortunately I cannot find the package anymore. You can try searching for the file `libfprint-vfs5011-git.tar.gz`. This is the driver I originally used (I am not the owner/maintainer) to add fingerprinting support inside libfprint. It used to be hosted [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/li/libfprint-vfs5011-git/libfprint-vfs5011-git.tar.gz).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and this worked for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui
```

You have to log out of your session and log back in afterwards.

## Supported readers (run command lsusb to find out the ID of your reader)

```
 045e:00bb    08ff:1683    08ff:2580    08ff:268d    147e:2020
 045e:00bc    08ff:1684    08ff:2660    08ff:268e    147e:3001
 045e:00bd    08ff:1685    08ff:2680    08ff:268f    1c7a:0603
 045e:00ca    08ff:1686    08ff:2681    08ff:2691
 0483:2015    08ff:1687    08ff:2682    08ff:2810
 0483:2016    08ff:1688    08ff:2683    08ff:5501
 05ba:0007    08ff:1689    08ff:2684    08ff:5731
 05ba:0008    08ff:168a    08ff:2685    138a:0001
 05ba:000a    08ff:168b    08ff:2686    138a:0005
 061a:0110    08ff:168c    08ff:2687    138a:0008
 08ff:1600    08ff:168d    08ff:2688    138a:0011
 08ff:1660    08ff:168e    08ff:2689    138a:0017
 08ff:1680    08ff:168f    08ff:268a    138a:0018
 08ff:1681    08ff:2500    08ff:268b    147e:1000
 08ff:1682    08ff:2550    08ff:268c    147e:2016
```

and

```
 0483:2015    147e:1003    147e:3000
 0483:2016    147e:2015    147e:3001
 147e:1000    147e:2016    147e:5002
 147e:1001    147e:2020    147e:5003
 147e:1002
```

from [“Fingerprint readers integration” team on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui)