# Driver 138a:0090 Fingerprint reader Validity Sensors

Tags: 14.04, drivers, scanner

I know that there has been similar posts about certain Fingerprint devices not being recognized, so I hope I'm not double posting.
In my case it's the

VFS7500 sensor from Validity Sensors

lsusb:
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:0090 Validity Sensors, Inc.

I tried installing it via fingerprint-gui and fprint and when this didn't work I tried it according to [Driver for Validity Sensors Fingerprint scanner](https://askubuntu.com/a/458782/510085) , but it seems that there is no support for this device yet. Is there a way to get it to work?

```
lsusb -s 001:004 -v

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:0090 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass        16 
  bDeviceProtocol       255 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x138a Validity Sensors, Inc.
  idProduct          0x0090 
  bcdDevice            1.64
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                0 
  iSerial                 1 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           53
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           5
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               4
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval              10
```

Comment: Check this https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94536.
Similar question at http://askubuntu.com/questions/756706/install-fingerprint-driver-138a0090-on-ubuntu-16-04-thinkpad-t460s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Fingerprint Driver 138a:0090 on Ubuntu 16.04 (ThinkPad T460s)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756706/install-fingerprint-driver-138a0090-on-ubuntu-16-04-thinkpad-t460s)

Comment: This answer should work for your issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/756706/install-fingerprint-driver-138a0090-on-ubuntu-16-04-thinkpad-t460s#answer-1028110