# Install Fingerprint Driver 138a:0090 on Ubuntu 16.04 (ThinkPad T460s)

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, 16.04, fingerprint-reader

I'm about to config my new fantastic T460s with Ubuntu 16.04 (because of Skylake Kernel issue I've to chose such new version)
I tried to use my fingerprint sensor which is 138a:0090 (lusb)
Fingerprint Gui doesn't recognize the device which is no wonder, because it is not on the compatibility list of it. Do I've to wait for a driver or is there something I can do about this?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: 16.04 hasn't been released, which makes your question off-topic. If your question was about how to make that particular fingerprint reader work, that would be a different thing.

Comment: That's exactly my question, I'm new to this community as writer so please excuse some mistakes in posting stuff

Comment: This is not supported yet, track the bug at https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94536

Comment: I have the same scanner on my new Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Yoga. Also no luck with fprint. I looked at the libfprint repo, but the project was last updated in 2008, and there does not seem to be a "driver request list" :(

Comment: this worked with my x1-carbon i7 3rd generation 3448 https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui Best luck

Comment: @Atomius try out barro32 's answer, it worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

I just got the finger print reader (138a:0090) working on my Thinkpad T460p!

1. Might be a good idea to remove `libpam-fprintd` if you've alread installed it:
   $`sudo apt remove libpam-fprintd`
2. Add the repo for `libpam-fprintd` which supports `138:0090`
   $`sudo add-apt-repository -u ppa:3v1n0/libfprint-vfs0090`
3. Install `libpam-fprintd`
   $`sudo apt install libpam-fprintd`
4. Enroll your index finder using:
   $`fprintd-enroll -f "right-index-finger" "$USER"`
5. Enroll all fingers:
   $`for finger in {left,right}-{thumb,{index,middle,ring,little}-finger}; do fprintd-enroll -f "$finger" "$USER"; done`

See here for more info: 
https://github.com/3v1n0/libfprint

Comment: IT WORKS! Tested it on a Lenovo T460p and it works flawlessly so far. Great work man!

Comment: I've followed your instruction, but when trying to enroll finger, I got `Enroll result: enroll-unknown-error`. I'm trying to get it working on T460p with Ubuntu 18.04 installed. Do you have any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: tried this on my Lenovo p50 laptop.  worked good until finger enrolls, output was: `list_devices failed: No devices available`

Comment: I tried on t460s, ubuntu 18.04, output at step 4: `list_devices failed: No devices available
`

Comment: Working for Lenovo P50 (ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: @shantanu How did you get that to work?  Did you type any other commands?  It doesn't work on mine, and I have the same model laptop, and same ubuntu version.

Comment: I had the same problem with my Lenovo P50 and Ubuntu 20.04 ... fixed it combining the following steps from [here][1] and [here][2]:

    sudo apt remove libpam-fprintd
    sudo add-apt-repository -u ppa:3v1n0/libfprint-vfs0090
    sudo apt install libfprint-2-tod-vfs0090 
    sudo apt install libpam-fprintd

Enroll your index finder using:

    fprintd-enroll -f "right-index-finger" "$USER"

 


  [1]: https://github.com/3v1n0/libfprint
  [2]: https://askubuntu.com/questions/756706/install-fingerprint-driver-138a0090-on-ubuntu-16-04-thinkpad-t460s

Answer (score 5):

I have an x1 carbon 4th gen which has the same fingerprint reader.  I looked through the upstram libfprint source, and it doesn't look supported yet, so that's why it's not working.  You will likely have to wait till someone creates a driver for it.

Answer (score 2):

The effort to reverse engineering the protocol has begun and found some success [here](https://github.com/nmikhailov/Validity90).  Keep an eye on that project for a driver.

Answer (score 0):

**For Ubuntu 16.04 or greater:**

Follow these steps to install the repo on a Lenovo B series (worked great with my Lenovo E450)

1. `$ sudo apt install libpam-fprintd`
2. `$ fprint-enroll`
3. Swipe your finger on Finger scanner