# 18.04: ThinkPad p50 Fingerprint Scanner not working even when recommended answer tried

Tags: 18.04, thinkpad, lts, fingerprint-reader

Installing [fprint](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fprint) and [fingerprint-gui](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui) do not enable the fingerprint scanner on a [Lenovo ThinkPad p50](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-p-series-laptops/thinkpad-p50) to work with Ubuntu.   If there is another linux-based OS that supports this, I would gladly switch to that, but I haven't found any.

The output from `lsusb` is:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0090 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b596 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Valadity Sensors, Inc. is my fingerprint sensor. How do I get it to work in Ubuntu?

Comment: What do I do then?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+driver+138a%3A0090 reveals multiple other folks with the same issue; the first links are right here in Askubuntu

Comment: i tried that, but the output was `list_devices failed: No devices available`

Comment: Multiple answers were shown in the Google link. Was it https://askubuntu.com/questions/756706/install-fingerprint-driver-138a0090-on-ubuntu-16-04-thinkpad-t460s which you tried?

Comment: yep, didn't work.  when I tried to enroll fingers, output from my last comment happened

Comment: OK, voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with my Lenovo P50 and Ubuntu 20.04 ... fixed it combining the following steps from [here](https://github.com/3v1n0/libfprint) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756706/install-fingerprint-driver-138a0090-on-ubuntu-16-04-thinkpad-t460s):

```
sudo apt remove libpam-fprintd
sudo add-apt-repository -u ppa:3v1n0/libfprint-vfs0090
sudo apt install libfprint-2-tod-vfs0090 
sudo apt install libpam-fprintd
```

Enroll your index finder using:

```
fprintd-enroll -f "right-index-finger" "$USER"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Okay

So, I went through the steps on the GitHub page (which I didn't know were there in the first place) and It worked fine.  I'm sorry for all your troubles.

Comment: Which GitHub page? Please post the link. Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind, found it [here](https://github.com/3v1n0/libfprint)

Comment: @xkcd thank you really

Comment: @MotassemMK Brother, my answer is the other one, in case you want to upvote :p