# Validity VFS301 Fingerprint scanner scans only once

Tags: 19.04, pam, fingerprint-reader

I've searched countless forums about fingerprint scanner support with ubuntu, I've gotten the system settings to show the fingerprint login prompt. It lets you scan once, but after that it refuses to light up the scanner nor does it attempt a scan. There are no errors with fprint. I'm running 19.04, Here's 
what it looks like in lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0005 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS301 Fingerprint Reader

Comment: What steps do you take to get the fingerprint scanner to work the one time?  Have you checked with the hardware manufacturer to see if they write a linux driver?

Comment: fprint-enroll or fingerprint-gui or use system settings under details>users>fingerprint login. no I'm using an HP pavilion dm4 it is detected and scans great the first time but doesn't activate after that

Comment: see [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/442838/driver-for-validity-sensors-fingerprint-scanner) for instructions to build from source and another answer that advises to install other packages (possible dependencies).  It couldn't hurt to contact/research the manufacturer of the fingerprint sensor (HP or Validity) and see if there is a driver for that specific hardware instead of a generic driver that might not support all features.

Comment: Awesome I'll get see about building from source, I've been trying for all of 2 days so hopefully a solution will arise.